# Olingo OData v4 with JAXRS 2.0

Tags: jax-rs, olingo

It's not clear to me whether Olingo OData v4 implementation is ready to use with JAX-RS 2.0.

I've developed a JAX-RS 2.0 REST Api, and from now on, I'd like to provide OData with it.
As far I've been able to figure out, there are two ways to implement OData v4 on server side:

```
Using servlets.
Using a JAX-RS implementation.
```

Could you redirect me to some documentation for knowing how to integrate Olingo with my JAXRS 2.0 REST Api?